# Is there a way to pass more than one filter flag options in a given PHP sanitize or validate filter?

Tags: php

For a given text field data input I want to limit the ASCII character value to be greater than 31 and less than 128.

I understand how to pass one flag option for a given sanitize filter ID.
Is it possible to pass two non-conflicting flag options?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.flags.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

I attempted to pass an additional flag using an additional comma.

```
filter_var($data, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
```

I am expecting to be able to pass two non-conflicting options such as `FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW`, `FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH` combination or the `FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW`, `FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH` combination. 
Unable to determine outcome due to not valid syntax for the function.

Comment: Did you try to place them in array and then set that array as parameter?
Eventually instead of separating them with comma, try with '|'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to take the bitwise OR (`|` operator) of the flag values and pass that:

```
filter_var($data, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
```

From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php):

> **options** 
>     Associative array of options or bitwise disjunction of flags

`"bitwise disjunction"` is another way of saying `bitwise OR`.

Comment: Thanks! I added this to my notes.